# Oracle - retrieve date having timestamp values

Tags: oracle, timestamp

We have a situation, where we have a table (say Forms) in Oracle DB which has a column (say edition_date) of type date. It was strictly meant to hold the date information in YYYY-MM-DD (ex: 2012-11-23)format with no timestamp value.

Unfortunately, due to a code problem, lot of rows got created with timestamp values. There are tons of records in this table, and I want to update only those rows which had this bad data. I can do that using the query

```
UPDATE forms SET edition_date = TRUNC( edition_date )
```

I want to add a where clause to it, so it updates only the bad data. The problem, I am not sure how to retrieve those rows that has timestamp added to it. Below is a snapshot of the data I have:

```
    FORM_ID    EDITION_DATE
    5          2012-11-23
    6          2012-11-23 11:00:15
    ..
    11         2010-07-11 15:23:22
    ..
    13         2011-12-31
```

I want to retrieve only the row with form ids 6 and 11. I trioed using the length functions but I think that is good for Strings only. Is there any way to do this. Thanks anyone  who can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A date has no format; you're only seeing how it's displayed. However, the answer to your question is, effectively, what you've said:

> I want to add a where clause to it, so it updates only the bad data.

So, where the date is not equal to the date without time:

```
update forms
   set edition_date = trunc(edition_date)
 where edition_date <> trunc(edition_date)
```

To ensure that this doesn't happen again you can add a [check constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CNCPT1660) to your table:

```
alter table forms 
  add constraint chk_forms_edition_date
      check ( edition_date = trunc(edition_date) );
```

I would advise against *all* of the above. Don't destroy potentially useful data. You should simply select `trunc(edition_date)` where you do not want time. You may want to use the time in the future.

You're correct, do not use LENGTH() etc for dates, it depends on your [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams145.htm#REFRN10119) settings and so could be different on a session-by-session basis. Always use date functions when dealing with dates.

Comment: +1 for the techniques, but I think that advising against implementing them may be rash without knowing more about the source of the timestamp. It may not relate to the date at all, but be an artifact of the time at which the record was created, for example. Quick note on the check constraint -- I'd definitely do this, but be aware of an optimiser problem in some version (of 10.2 I think) which caused the constraint to also be applied as a predicate that artificially reduced the estimated cardinality.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I think your suggestion is awesome and would take care of my concerns of any unwanted updates. I agree with you on not removing the timestamp's as it in fact provides additional data. I am still talking with our customer on this and hope they would agree to the suggestion.